# mysql vs mysqli not the same result?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this old mysql query:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM nf_users 
    WHERE points > 
        (SELECT points FROM nf_users WHERE id = 1) 
    AND played > 0");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

$rank = mysql_num_rows($sql)+1;
```

This gives the `$rank` a value of `2578`. Now if I try to do the same with mysqli like this:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT id FROM nf_users 
    WHERE points > 
        (SELECT points FROM nf_users WHERE id = 1) 
    AND played > 0");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);

$rank = mysqli_num_rows($sql)+1;
```

the `$rank` now only says `1`?

What am I doing wrong?

Please help and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Have you tried some other querys? Is the connection the same in both querys?

Comment: Perhaps your query is faulty and no results are given. Therefore 0 + 1 would result in 1.. Please use mysqli_query() or die(mysqli_error()) or such things.. Ps switching to mysqli_* functions without using prepared statements is useless..

Comment: maybe it's just me, but where do you see a function `mysqli_num_rows()`? Maybe you use `mysql_num_rows()`, that results in an (probably not display) warning and a return value of `false`, that `+1` leads to `1`? Update: Found it :) HOwever, I recommend the object-based style `$sql->num_rows`

Comment: @Luceos You are so wrong... `mysql`-extension is oudated and not maintained for a while now. Switching to a `MySQLi` is _in every case_ useful! Recommend to stick with `mysql` is bad ;)

Comment: @Luceos Since there are no parameters in his query, why does he need to use a prepared statement?

Comment: But Luceos is right about checking for errors. If the query failed, `mysqli_num_rows()` will return false, and `false+1` is `1`.

Comment: @kingCrunch: without prepared statement, be it mysql, mysqli, pdo or some foo bar api, all are same. Doesn't make any difference as of now.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't make difference in the real life but here on Stackoverflow is a Great Movement against old good mysql ext :)

Comment: @itachi Thats simply wrong! http://php.net/mysqli-overview See the table at the end.

Comment: @YourCommonSense You get it wrong: It's not about "a movement on SO", it's about the fact, that `mysql` not maintained for a really long time anymore. I mean it: _Really_ long time. Beside that such answers like "it doesn't care", doesn't help, tutorials also propagate the usage, so do you have a better idea to convince people not to use it anymore? Think about the word "maintain": No support for newer mysql-features, only critical security fixes (if ever) and so on. In my eyes `mysql` should be treatened as a bug on its own ;)

Comment: I meant to say that switching to mysqli is smart, but it would be wise to switch to pdo and prepared statements any how. So if you are migrating to mysqli_ just for the sake of it getting unsupported, then why not spend your effort to learn create prepared statements on pdo; the reason mysql functions are getting unsupported is because they do not support prepared statements, which by itself are much safer. There are plenty of libraries to aid you if you can't manage by yourself..

And I agree to @KingCrunch, mysql_ functions should be treated as bugs.

Comment: @kingcrunch: if you do not use the advanced features that new apis provide, then how is it make any difference in real life or programming world? It is still same. I.e. Vulnerable to injections.

Comment: @itachi Well, go with `mysql`, but just don't recommend it. It's not required, that you use, or even "see" features (think of security issues, or performance). Also, I promise you: The moment you have your enterprise-level application up and running and you want to use a feature, you'll regret to stick with `mysql` ;) You can start a project with "Why should I use a db at all? I just need to save a text in a file", but you wouldn't, do you? ;) But changing later is usually a huge task.

Comment: @kingcrunch: actually my point of view was different than yourscommonsense. I definitely prefer pdo with prepared statement. (i even forgot mysql_* apis syntaxes). I just wanted to say that, if you do not use the advanced features of mysqli or pdo there wouldn't be any difference in functionality (in a loose sense) than the old api. So better use prepared statement.

Answer (score 3):

Well, aside from the num_rows issue which most likely caused by a simple typo, there is a more important thing to mention:

Selecting rows instead of their count is a very bad practice, which burden your application with unnecessary load. Always ask your database to do the count, not API

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM nf_users 
        WHERE points > (SELECT points FROM nf_users WHERE id = 1) 
        AND played > 0";
$res  = mysqli_query($connect,$sql) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($connect)." [$sql]");
$row  = mysqli_fetch_row($res);
$rank = $row[0]+1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Neither your `mysql_xxx()` code nor your `mysqli_xx()` code does any checking for errors.

This is your fundamental mistake. Gracefully handling errors and unexpected events is one of the keys to writing robust code.

In this case, it is clear what is happening: The original `mysql_query()` is working, but the `mysqli_query()` is throwing an error. In the absence of an error handler, the program is falling through to getting the num rows (which is `false` because of the error), adding 1, and the end result is 1.

This much is clear. So the question is not 'what is happening', but 'why'?

There's insufficient code here to be certain, but the obvious difference between the two code snippets is the introduction of the `$connect` variable.

As you obviously know already, the `mysqli` functions require you to pass the connection object, whereas the old `mysql` functions don't (if you don't pass it, they default to a hidden global connection - this is one of the design flaws that has led to the old `mysql` extension being considered bad to use).

My guess would be that although you're passing `$connect`, the connection variable is not actually populated. The most likely cause I can think of would be if the connection was made in another part of the program, and you haven't passed `$connect` into this function.

But if you add some error handling, this will become clear.

Comment: Adding some actual code will make this good answer even better.